# How to rotate an Actor with pinch gesture

Tags: android, rotation, libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to rotate an actor using the pinch gesture. The actor is actually rotating but there are times that the rotation is "stucked". I logged the deltaRotDeg (delta rotation in degrees) and there are times when the values jump. For example it's rotating in -42.25918 degrees then it will jump to 317.7408 degrees. I followed the rotation math here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319401/Simple-Gestures-on-Android

And here's my code. Is my math wrong or there's something wrong in the code?

```
public ActorGestureListener gestureListener = new ActorGestureListener() {
 @Override
    public void pinch(InputEvent event, Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2)  {
        Actor actor = event.getListenerActor();
        if(actor.getName().equals("valve")){
            Vector2 a = initialPointer2.sub(initialPointer1);
            Vector2 b = pointer2.sub(pointer1);
            a = a.nor();
            b = b.nor();
            float deltaRot = (float)(Math.atan2(b.y,b.x) - Math.atan2(a.y,a.x));
            float deltaRotDeg = (float)((deltaRot*180)/Math.PI);
            world.getValve().rotate(deltaRotDeg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know where exactly the error is, but I think it has something to do with -42.25918° + 360° = 317.7408°.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
float deltaRotDeg = (float)((deltaRot*180)/Math.PI);
```

with

```
float deltaRotDeg = (float)(((deltaRot*180)/Math.PI + 360) % 360);
```

Comment: Won't this prevent it from getting negative?

Comment: Yes it would. That's the point. Keep the angle in 0 to 360 OR -180 to 180. Both are fine. Your current code can make it -360 to +360 and have abrupt jumps. If you change it, you'll know where the jumps would be. Good luck.